# Copying variables to local text file from multiple ssh awk output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ssh, scripting

I'm reasonably new to shell scripting, so I've had difficulty applying the answers to similar questions to my problem.

I am trying to ssh to a remote server, perform multiple awk commands, and return the value of each to a local .txt file. I am also trying to ssh to other servers, perform similar commands, and return them to the same text file.

If i manually ssh into the remote server and run `df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}` I get the % used value for the root directory from the df -h command.
Thus far, I have the following, but while it enters and exits the remote server it doesn't save the value.

```
> testfile.txt

ssh {$CURRENT_ENV} << EOF
VAL=\$(df -h | awk '\$6 == "/" {print \$5; exit}')
echo "\$VAL > testfile.txt"
exit
EOF
```

I've looked at single line awk returns, but as I have multiple commands to run it doesn't seem optimal. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: With respect to `I have multiple commands to run` - I highly recommend you only run the minimum command(s) that you need to run on the remote machine and run the rest locally for robustness, ease of maintenance, etc. For example in this case you could do `ssh 'df' | awk` instead of `ssh 'df | awk'`. Then, for example, if you had to debug it you could tweak it to `ssh 'df' | tee file | awk` to create a local copy of the `df` output - a generally more impactful change if your starting point was `ssh 'df | awk'`.

Comment: So when  you say `I am trying to ssh to a remote server, perform multiple awk commands, and return the value of each to a local .txt file` - I recommend you don't do that. Instead ssh to a remote server, perform the absolute minimal command(s) necessary to gather the data you need, save  that data to your local server, then perform multiple awk commands locally on the local copy of the data and return the value of each to a local .txt file. Taking customer requirements for allowed data transfer (if applicable) and data transfer size/rates into account of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `ssh` command. Using a here-document is a good idea. You can improve it in two ways by:

- indenting with TABs owing to the `<<-` syntax. This is purely cosmetic and makes your code more readable.
- avoiding the escaping of special characters like `$` by quoting `EOF`. This is not only cosmetic but makes your code less error-prone.

This gives:

```
ssh {$CURRENT_ENV} <<- 'EOF'
        VAL=$(df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}')
        echo "$VAL > testfile.txt"
        exit
EOF
```

(we could even put a tabulation before EOF)

Now your code :

- You don't tell us what CURRENT_ENV is. I assume this is something like `user@server`. To use that variable, write `"$CURRENT_ENV"`, not '{CURRENT_ENV}'. Unless you know what you are doing, when using a variable, always enclose it in double-quotes to avoid any undesirable side-effect.
- You put the result of `df` into variable `VAL` and write its content to `textfile.txt`:

  - As a universal convention, use lower cases for you variable names (unless they are exported to the environment which is not the case here); i.e. this should be `val`, not `VAL`.
  - `echo "$val > testfile.txt"` won't write anything into textfile.txt because your redirection is inside double-quotes, and thus belongs to the text that is `echo`-ed. Proper command would be `echo "$val" > testfile.txt`
  - Now, think about it: all this, including this `echo` is executed on the remote server, therefore this will create the file `testfile.txt` there, not on your machine. This is not what you want, so let's remove that `echo` line. Let's also remove `val=` since `val` is not needed any longer.
  - The `exit` command is of no need. Once the last command will be read and executed, the `ssh` session ends anyway.

We are left with this;

```
ssh "$CURRENT_ENV" <<- 'EOF'
        df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}'
EOF
```

(remember this is a tabulation before `df` but single spaces wouldn't harm in this case)

As it is now, your code outputs everything to your terminal. Let's now redirect this to your local file `testfile.txt` :

```
ssh {$CURRENT_ENV} <<- 'EOF' > testfile.txt
        df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}'
EOF
```

OK, this works for one server. You told us there were actually several ones. You don't show us your code, so I will assume there is a loop somewhere:

```
for ssh_target in u1@server1 u2@server2 ...; do
    ssh "$ssh_target" <<- 'EOF' > testfile.txt
        df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}'
EOF
done
```

Almost there! The problem with this command is that each loop overwrites the content of `testfile.txt`. The solution is to redirect the `for` loop, NOT the `ssh` command inside it:

```
for ssh_target in u1@server1 u2@server2 ...; do
    ssh "$ssh_target" <<- 'EOF'
        df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}'
EOF
done > testfile.txt
```

(the redirection must be put after `done`)

Here it is!

Comment: Thanks @Ed. This is intentional. I'm afraid the OP could copy-paste my code and then get plain spaces instead of tabs, which will trigger an error they probably won't understand (EOF not found). So I kept EOF left aligned in my answer. I only indented commands which won't be affected by additional leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the quoting `EOF` trick!

Comment: Thanks! This works great for looping through and getting all the terminal output. When it saves to the text file, it also saves the ssh initial login/ system load information. Is there a way to tweak this to purely return the output of `df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}' ` that is displayed when this is run directly in the remote environment! Thank you again for the detailed step by step, as it made a lot of things clearer for me

Comment: @ebrithilotho This banner only appears when you call `ssh` without any command in parameter (i.e. you want a command line). You can either give a command instead of providing it through the here-document (i.e. `ssh serveur 'df -h'`) but since your command is rather complex, you can just give your shell itself as a command: `ssh serveur bash <<- EOF ...`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this:

```sh
# Write all of this script's stdout to testfile.txt
> testfile.txt

# Run df -h on remote host, and pipe the stdout of df -h to awk
ssh "$host" df -h | awk '$6 == "/" {print $5; exit}'
```

Note that if you specify a filepath with `df` then you can get information for just that filepath. In your case you are only interested in `/`, so you can specify that.

If you are only interested in the percent used, you can use the `--ouput=pcent` option, and then use `tail` to get only the percentage part (leaving out the `Use%` header):

```sh
df --output=pcent / | tail -n 1
```

This will produce output with one or two leading spaces if the percent used is less than 100%. The leading spaces can be deleted with `tr`:

```sh
df --output=pcent / | tail -n 1 | tr -d ' '
```

If for some reason you want to avoid having two pipes, but you still want to remove leading spaces, you can use `awk`:

```sh
df --output=pcent / | awk 'NR == 2 {print $1}'
```

However using `awk` might be slower, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print anything to local file, just do redirect immediately after EOF
here is example how to write VAL to remotefile and to localfile. Also you can use df --output pcent to show only percentage column. Unfortunately there is no option to hide header, so tail -n1

```
ssh {$CURRENT_ENV} << EOF >>localfile.txt
VAL=\$(df --output=pcent /|tail -n1)
echo "$VAL" > remotefile.txt
echo "$VAL" # for localfile
exit
EOF
```